# MySQL Alternative QUERY for: NOT EXISTS/ NOT IN

Tags: mysql

I am facing a problem to execute DELETE or UPDATE query using NOT IN / NOT EXISTS in my database. I have 2 table `USERS` and `REMARK`.

Hints: `Users` table record = 9880 AND `Remark` table record = 38943

I want to delete all data from `REMARK` table where `profile_id` does not exist in the `users` table.

To execute the operation I used this query:

```
UPDATE remark 
SET status = '0'
WHERE profile_id  NOT IN (SELECT * FROM users); 
Or
DELETE from remark 
WHERE profile_id NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users); 
Or
DELETE FROM remark
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     select * from users
     where users.profile_id = remark. profile_id);
```

Result = #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Please help me.

Comment: Please, consider to accept the answer if you consider it correct. Otherwise, it would be nice to give a feedback to the author of the answer to let him ameliorate the answer and so to help you!

Answer (score 1):

You're close;

```
UPDATE remark SET status = '0' WHERE profile_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT * FROM users);
```

should most likely be;

```
UPDATE remark SET status = '0' WHERE profile_id NOT IN
    (SELECT profile_id FROM users);
```

since `*` will select all fields from users, you can't compare them with `profile_id`, you need to just select the field you want to compare.

Naturally, you can delete using the same `WHERE` clause;

```
DELETE FROM remark WHERE profile_id NOT IN
    (SELECT profile_id FROM users);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM REMARK
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM USERS
    WHERE profile_id=REMARK.profile_id
)
```

Do take note that the below would not work (or any other close variations):

```
DELETE FROM REMARK r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM USERS
    WHERE profile_id=r.profile_id
)
```

Due to referencing. Credits: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-delete-records-in-one-table-not-in-another/